# How can I sync data between a Android app , Webserver and Web app?

Tags: android, sql, rdbms

I have an app that runs on SQL database. I'm making a similar website now that is
going to use the same data. I already connected the basics like email and username both from Android app and Web app to server. Im using PDO at the server side. This may be answered many times before but some questions are as old as from 2012.

Android app and web app is going to be dependent on the same data

I want to make sure Im doing everything right from the start.

What ways are there to connect from Android to server read/write data (Now Im only using HttpURLConnection to write data)?

Could I bulk the data and send it for example one time after session ended or should I update the database after every transaction from Android side?

[image]

Comment: You can build a service layer in the middle so that your Android and Web app both use the same endpoints to get the data.

Comment: I dont understand downvote without explanation

Comment: @KhawajaAsim Something like ContentProvider?

Comment: Like middle layer API, so that if in future you want to create a IOS or Windows app too then you just have to connect your application (may be with content providers of your application) to the API endpoint to get required data.

Comment: Ok, I need to look up that

Comment: Vote up if you find my comments useful

Comment: Do you have any links to any to example?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/139549/discussion-between-khawaja-asim-and-waffles-inc).

Answer (score 0):

1) Yes HttpURLConnection will the best way to connect server.

2) You have to update database in every android transaction so when ever you will refresh your web page, it will show you latest data in both side(Android app & web).

Comment: you can also use Socket to make connection.